# During Catholic confirmation, what criteria should be used to choose a saint?

Tags: catholicism, saint, confirmation

When being confirmed in the Catholic Church it is customary to choose a saint.  What criteria should we use to choose this saint?  Should one choose a saint they like?  Would like to be like?  Or one that has strengths where I have weakness?  What guidance has the magisterium given for this process?

Comment: The Church has no requirements that I see for choosing a confirmation name. In fact, looking at the Catechism's description of the Confirmation rite, a "confirmation name" isn't even mentioned or referred to. Nor does the Code of Canon Law contain such a reference.

Comment: Thanks I did not know that.  I am not sure why we are told to choose a saint then.  I prepared for confirmation in the 90s and did not end up finishing and we had to pick a saint.  Now I am going through the process again and asked to choose a saint.  Different churches in different states.

Comment: I guess regardless of if it is required or not any tips on how to choose one?

Comment: It is general practice and tradition to take a confirmation name, as far as I know (I did); but as this site is focused on definite, factual answers to (primarily) academic questions, I can't really help beyond saying "The Church doesn't have any formal teaching." Unless of course it does. I don't think so, but I'll check.

Comment: @MattGutting Choosing a saint's name is still done.  There are more sources than Canon Law and the Catechism.  If I can dig up the USCCB's RCIA book I'll see if there is a section on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your instincts are good. I found this answer [here](http://www.catholic.com/quickquestions/what-happened-to-confirmation-names):

> The custom of adopting a saint’s name at confirmation was done in
>   order to adopt the saint as a special heavenly patron or to honor a
>   saint to whom one had a special devotion. In short, the purpose was to
>   give the confirmand the opportunity to develop his understanding of
>   and reliance on the communion of saints.

In my own case I chose Joseph as my confirmation name because we had a neighbor that was a good Catholic role model named Joseph (he was our boy scout troop leader) and I also thought Mary's husband didn't get enough devotion.

Apparently some parishes no longer ask you to chose a confirmation name. I think that's sad. Misplaced liturgical "reform".